# how to create deep relations between same model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

based on this tutorial

**Self-Referential Association**

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

we can see the friends that we added, and also go to the profile of the user and see his friends using this code:

```
  <% for friendship in @user.friendships %>
     <%= friendship.friend.username %>
  <% end %>

  <% for user in @user.inverse_friends %>
    <li><%= user.username %></li>
  <% end %>
```

but how can I go deeper then that and see the friends of a friend, I mean if you go to profile of one user you can see his frineds through friensips, this is level 1, and how can I see the friends of his friends in the same page, is it possible?.

I gave this is exemple from railscasts cause my app works the same, and I need to go deeper cause I need to make jqueryChart and I need more branches, in order to have more branches I need to get the relation between friends of a user and frineds of his friends (man, tha's hard).
Thank you very much.

```
                                         User
level 1         user.friend 1            user.friend 2                user.friend 3
level 2    friend 4 of user.friend 1     friend 1 of user.friend 2
level 3    friend 5 of friend 4
```

so probably this will make it more clear, the how can I get to the leve 2 at least on the same User page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you could add this to your User model to be easier to get all friends

```
has_many :friends, :through => friendships
```

So you can now do

```
<% for friend in @user.friends %>
  <%=friend.username %>
<% end %>
```

instead of

```
<% for friendship in @user.friendships %>
  <%= friendship.friend.username %>
<% end %>
```

And using each method

```
<% @user.friends.each do |friend| %>
  <%=friend.username %>
<% end %>
```

So, I think this solves your problem but it's not a really good solution for prodution.

```
<% @user.friends.each do |friend| %>
  <%=friend.username %>
  <%= friend.friends.each do |fof| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= fof.username %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, why this works? Because friends are actually also from User model, and have the same methods like the @user, so each friend has also the friends method on it.
And you could all the nesting you wan't. In that screencast he uses user.friendships instead of user.friends just because he needs the friendship_id to make the link_to for deleting the friendship. So if you just want to display username you can use user.friends directly.

Why this can be a bad practice? Because you make a new database query for each friend you have to get their friends. But maybe it actually isn't that bad, if there is some caching, those querys should be better than a join actually, because the join query would be unique to the current user and the cache of it would be used from him only, if there is a separate query for each user, then those cached querys would be used more times, because all friends would see other friends friends.

Comment: there was a few things to workout but in the end I have it done, at least 2 levels I have. Thank you. Still, I am not quite sure about the correctness of the code the way I did it, but at least I see some results.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty deep problem, and to do it right will take some effort.  Checkout:

[Graph Edges Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836800/graph-edges-rails)

Comment: well, thanks for the link. I'll look into it more but I must say it's looking very scary.